# How do I make one dialog be infront of other dialogs so that his dim will be on top of tham

Tags: android, dialog

I am managing multiple custom dialogs in a `LinkedList`.

The first dialog that was shown always has `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` set and all the other shown dialogs have `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` cleard from thier flags.

**My problem is that the dialogs are not influenced by the `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` affect of firstDialog and I think it is because firstDialog is created first.**

I tried the following methods:

- Using `firstDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().bringToFront()` => didn't work
- Canceling all the dialogs and than reshowing them when the `firstDialog` is shown last. But when I canceled the windows, they got removed from the LinkedList.
- Dismissing all the dialogs and than reshowing them when `firstDialog` is shown last. But the dialogs just don't reshow.

  ```
  ....

  LinkedList<CustomDialog> dialogList = new LinkedList<CustomDialog>();
  CustomDialog firstDialog = new CustomDialog();
  firstDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
  dialogList.add(firstDialog);
  CustomDialog temp;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
          temp = new CustomDialog();
          temp.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
          dialogList.add(temp);
  }

  for(CustomDialog itr : dialogList)
  {
          itr.show();
  }

  ....
  ```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Post your relevant code snippet.

Comment: I thought you can only have one dialog open from the same activity at the same time?  Opening the second one will close the first one (clearing the FLAG_DIM_BEHIND).

Comment: You can show as much dialogs as you want, what happens usually is that the second dialog opens above the first.

Comment: @DorShaked In theory, yes, but in practice, I think the one on the background is closed.  Did you try this with the second dialog being smaller size than the first?  Do you still see the first one on the background?

Comment: @AleksG yes, I know it works with my 'CustomDialog' and I didn't do any special procedure for it to happen so my guess is that it will work with a simple 'Dialog' to.

Answer (score 0):

I use multiple dialogs over each other in my app, but use them in separate classes.

```
public class PopFilters extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{}
```

and call them by this

```
PopFilters(NewMain.nmain).show();
```

The problem I have is when the phone is oriented in portrait using

```
FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
```

it causes the dialog to flicker when opening, when in landscape, no problem.  It drives me crazy, but other than that no issues.